# how to select rows from a dataframe1 in R where dataframe$1column is found somewhere in dataframe2$column

Tags: r

I need to create a new dataframe from rows from dataframe1, such that the value of dataframe1$column is a value found in dataframe2$colum

the dataframes are:

```
y <- "name,number,lunch  
joe,2,peaches  
steve,5,hotdog  
jon,7,clamroll  
nick,11,sloppyJoe"


x <- "number,office  
1,1b  
2,1a  
3,2s  
4,4d  
5,f4  
6,f4  
7,h3  
8,g3  
9,j7  
10,d3 
11,jk"  

df1 <- read.csv(textConnection(df1), header=TRUE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)  
df2 <- read.csv(textConnection(df2), header=TRUE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I have tried:

```
df3 <- df1[which(df1$number == df2$number), ]
```

to no avail.
How do I properly do this in R?  I could write a perl script, but I have about 100 of these sets and don't want to create more temp files.

Comment: The answers to this question are exactly what you need: [Match dataframe rows according to two variables (Indexing)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878773/match-dataframe-rows-according-to-two-variables-indexing)

Comment: @Joshua : how could I miss that one...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

again, the `%in%` trick :

```
> df1[df1$number %in% df2$number,]
   number office
2       2     1a
5       5     f4
7       7     h3
11     11     jk
```

For what it's worth, you can easily just do a merge if you want to combine them. In this case I'd say that's the cleanest solution : gives you every office of the occuring employees, and matches them :

```
> merge(df1,df2)
  number office  name     lunch
1      2     1a   joe   peaches
2      5     f4 steve    hotdog
3      7     h3   jon  clamroll
4     11     jk  nick sloppyJoe
```

Check the help files of merge for more options, you can do a whole lot with it.

Answer (score 1):

Joris' answer is spot on. The `merge()` command can also be useful for this type of stuff. If you are familiar with SQL joins, you can draw parallels between most of the options in `merge()` and the different join operations.

```
#Inner join
> merge(df1,df2)
  number office  name      lunch
1      2   1a     joe  peaches  
2      5   f4   steve   hotdog  
3      7   h3     jon clamroll  
4     11     jk  nick  sloppyJoe

#Right join:
> merge(df1,df2, all.x = TRUE)
   number office  name      lunch
1       1   1b    <NA>       <NA>
2       2   1a     joe  peaches  
3       3   2s    <NA>       <NA>
4       4   4d    <NA>       <NA>
5       5   f4   steve   hotdog  
6       6   f4    <NA>       <NA>
7       7   h3     jon clamroll  
8       8   g3    <NA>       <NA>
9       9   j7    <NA>       <NA>
10     10    d3   <NA>       <NA>
11     11     jk  nick  sloppyJoe
```