# R Using a for() loop to fill one dataframe with another

Tags: r, for-loop

I have two dataframes and I wish to insert the values of one dataframe into another (let's call them `DF1` and `DF2`).

`DF1` consists of 2 columns 1 and 2. Column 1 (`col1`) contains characters a to z and `col2` has values associated with each character (from a to z)

`DF2` is a dataframe with 3 columns. The first two consist of every combination of `DF1$col1` so: aa ab ac ad etc; where the first letter is in `col1` and the second letter is in `col2`

I want to create a simple mathematical model utilizing the values in `DF1$col2` to see the outcomes of every possible combination of objects in `DF1$col1`
The first step I wanted to do is to transfer values from `DF1$col2` to `DF2$col3` (values from `DF2$col3` should be associated to values in DF2col1), but that's where I'm stuck. I currently have

```
for(j in 1:length(DF2$col1))
{
  ## this part is to use the characters in DF2$col1 as an input 
  ## to yield the output for DF2$col3--
  input=c(DF2$col1)[j]

  ## This is supposed to use the values found in DF1$col2 to fill in DF2$col3

  g=DF1[(DF1$col2==input),"pred"]

  ## This is so that the values will fill in DF2$col3--
  DF2$col3=g
}
```

When I run this, `DF2$col3` will be filled up with the same value for a specific character from `DF1` (e.g. `DF2$col3` will have all the rows filled with the value associated with character "a" from `DF1`)
What exactly am I doing wrong?

Thanks a bunch for your time

Comment: Have you tried `merge`? See http://stackoverflow.com/q/4878773/210673

Comment: Why do you consider `pred` as a colname since you talked about `col1` and `col2` for `df1`?

Comment: It was a mistake; I forgot to replace pred with df1$col2 ~_~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should really use `merge` for this as @Aaron suggested in his comment above, but if you insist on writing your own loop, than you have the problem in your last line, as you assign `g` value to the whole `col3` column. You should use the `j` index there also, like:

```
for(j in 1:length(DF2$col1))
{
  DF2$col3[j] = DF1[(which(DF1$col2 == DF2$col1[j]), "pred"]
}
```

If this would not work out, than please also post some sample database to be able to help in more details (as I do not know, but have a gues what could be `"pred"`).

Comment: Oh geez--I didn't realize that merge could be used like this (newbie here). Thanks to both you and @Aaron. I forgot to change "pred" to "DF1$col2", but I wanted to let you know that the alternative code works as well.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you are trying to do is a simple join, that is, match `DF1$col1` to `DF2$col1` and copy the corresponding value from `DF1$col2` into `DF2$col3`. Try this:

```
DF1 <- data.frame(col1=letters, col2=1:26, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
DF2 <- expand.grid(col1=letters, col2=letters, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
DF2$col3 <- DF1$col2[match(DF2$col1,  DF1$col1)]
```

This uses the function `match()`, which, as the documentation states, "returns a vector of the positions of (first) matches of its first argument in its second." The values you have in `DF1$col1` are unique, so there will not be any problem with this method.

As a side note, in R it is usually better to vectorize your work rather than using explicit loops.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understood your question, but you can try this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1=letters[1:26], col2=sample(1:100, 26))
df2 <- with(df1, expand.grid(col1=col1, col2=col1))
df2$col3 <- df1$col2
```

The last command use recycling (it could be writtent as `rep(df1$col2, 26)` as well).

The results are shown below:

```
> head(df1, n=3)
  col1 col2
1    a   68
2    b   73
3    c   45
> tail(df1, n=3)
   col1 col2
24    x   22
25    y    4
26    z   17
> head(df2, n=3)
  col1 col2 col3
1    a    a   68
2    b    a   73
3    c    a   45
> tail(df2, n=3)
    col1 col2 col3
674    x    z   22
675    y    z    4
676    z    z   17
```